# How To Extract Excel Sheet Name From Workbook Using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am working on payroll to import attendance of employees. Here's my code to import the excel sheet.

> ```
>  Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
>
>  Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet = Nothing
>
>  Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter = Nothing
> ```

```
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .Filter = "Excel files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel (97-2003) files(*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Title = "Import data from Excel file"
    End With
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fname As String
        fname = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & fname & " '; " & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Test")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        ResultGrid.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()
    End If
```

The problem is I want to have the sheet name dynamic From `"[Sheet1$]"` to any name. I am new to this concept so find it tough to find the relevant solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a textbox and enter sheet name in it, then change your command to something like this : 


`MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & txtSheetName.text & "$]", MyConnection)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fname, 0, True)

' For the first sheet in an excel spreadsheet
xlWorkSheet = CType(xlApp.Sheets(1), _
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
Dim strSheetName as String = xlSheetName.Name
```

Your strSheetName string has the name of the sheet which you can pass.
If you have more than one sheet and want all the data from them then

```
Dim strSheetName as New List(of String)
For each xlWorkSheet in xlApp.Sheets
    strSheetName.Add(xlWorkSheet.Name)
Next
```